# How to check for a condition periodically till it passes or a duration expires

Tags: spring-boot, scheduled-tasks, spring-scheduled

Our spring-boot application gets a notification to update a resource and first needs to check if a resource is available to update i.e. is locked by another thread for the update (the locking thread would unlock it once task completed).

**The check for the resource needs to be started once received event/notification to update the resource and is to be done in a fixed interval (e.g. 100 ms) till a timeout duration.**

- Thread receives a notification to update a resource.
- It first checks if the resource is not already locked for update
- If the resource already locked the thread needs to check again periodically till a set timeout duration.
- If on checking again resource is found unlocked the thread would mark it locked and start the update.

**We used Awaitility for the same but it is a test-focused utility e.g. below**

```
await().atMost(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS).pollInterval(10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).until(future::isDone);
```

**Is an Executor service or scheduler service better way** to accomplish the same?

If so a sample would be very useful.

Comment: i would use the @async functionality in spring https://www.baeldung.com/spring-async to start an async task and then write all the logic you demand in this async task.

A scheduler is something that will periodically start based on a given interval. This cannot be started on command, usually you set a fixed time for the scheduler to start.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf But we need to call the async task again and again i.e. poll till a timeout or the condition is met. Can we implement that through async?

Comment: you probably dont even need async, you just put the polling in a while loop